# Caching plugin and normal controllers with duplicate names

Tags: cakephp, caching, cakephp-2.0

I'm running into a problem related to caching, plugins and duplicate model names in Cake 2.0. My application has several controllers containing only actions for public use (view, index and equivalents). The data is managed by a CMS which is added as a plugin, some names of the plugin's controller are the same.

For example, I have a PostsController in my application and a PostsController for the plugin. The plugin controller extends `PluginAppController` and the public controller extends `AppController` as per the manual. As soon as caching is kicked in (by setting `debug` to `0`) the problems start. Cake tries to access a non-existing `add` action in the controller which extends `AppController` and the public application tries to access methods from the `PluginAppController`.

I don't understand why Cake would do this and it creates all kinds of errors (blank pages, lost sessions) which aren't logged properly as well. Everything was working well while the app still ran on Cake 1.3 and also in 2.0 production mode.

The file `cake_core_file_map` in the `/tmp/cache/persistent/` directory seems to be causing the issue. As soon as I remove this and reload either of the views, it renders correctly. So the procedure is as follows:

- Load `http://www.example.com/admin/posts` successfully;
- Load `http://www.example.com/posts` (it fails to render);
- Clear the cache (or just cake_core_file_map);
- Load `http://www.example.com/posts` successfully;
- Load `http://www.example.com/admin/posts` (which now fails to load properly).

My guess is Cake fails to save the correct references to the plugin and main application paths in `cake_core_file_map`, but I have no clue how to force Cake to behave nicely in that regard.

Does anybody know how to stop Cake from confusing the plugin's controllers with the other ones with duplicate names?

**EDIT**

This issue might be related to a bug in Cake, as [this report](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2108-fatal-error-plugin-appmodel-not-found-with-caching-enabled-in-certain-circumstance) mentions similar problems and `cake_core_file_map` as well. The fix mentioned [here](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2108-fatal-error-plugin-appmodel-not-found-with-caching-enabled-in-certain-circumstance#ticket-2108-16) doesn't work unfortunately.

**EDIT 2**
There is indeed some custom routing going on, which was working normally in Cake 1.3. This is from `routes.php`:

```
Router::connect('/plugin_name', array('plugin' => 'plugin_name', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/admin/*', array('plugin' => 'plugin_name', 'controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be a known issue (which doesn't make it less annoying) and will only be fixed in a next major release, as per [this Cake bug report](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2378).

PHP 5.2 doesn't have namespace support which is apparently needed for Cake to support duplicate classnames. PHP 5.3 has namespace support and Cake 3.0 will require that version.

Comment: This isn't exactly a CakePHP bug, but more of an improper use of PHP 5.2.  The only reason it will be available in CakePHP 3 is because it will require PHP 5.3, which supports namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

May be it would be helpfull to override Cake' standard cache file names for Plugin to make Cache engine keep it separately. 
In main bootstrap file while loading plugin:

```
CakePlugin::loadAll(array('Plugin' => array('bootstrap' => true));
```

In Plugin direcrory 
/app/Plugin/Plugin/Config/bootstrap.php

```
<?php
Cache::config('_cake_core_', array(
    'engine' => 'File',
    'prefix' => 'cake_core_plugin_',
    'path' => CACHE . 'persistent' . DS,
    'serialize' => true,
    'duration' => '+999 days',
));
?>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for CakePHP 2.*. This post is from 6 years ago, but it still saves the day!

Answer (score 0):

Are there conflicting routes between the main app and the plugin?  This sounds like you may need to create a route for your /posts and another for /admin/posts in your main app.  This should override the routes from the plugin causing any conflict.  Of course, clear your cache before trying the change.

```
//main app posts route
Router::connect(
    '/posts',
    array(
        'controller' => 'Posts'
        'action' => 'index'
    )
);

//plugin posts route
Router::connect(
    '/admin/posts',
    array(
        'controller' => 'Posts'
        'action' => 'index',
        'plugin' => 'CmsPlugin'
    )
);
```

Comment: I've updated my question with the relevant entries from my routes.php. Does that look in order?

Comment: The routes you listed both point back to the plugin (hence the plugin key in your array). But, your question states that one route should point to the plugin's Post controller while another route should point to the app's Posts controller.  Is the Plugin named Posts too -- so there are two controllers and a Plugin named Posts?

Comment: Also, remember that the controller naming conventions changed with CakePHP 2.0.  You need to be sure that you capitalize controller names properly.

Comment: There is a controller named Posts in the plugin and one in the app. The plugin has a different name (let's say `cms`). The posted routes are only my plugin routes, there are three other routes (two related to an RSS feed and one connecting a Maps controller to Cake's home). Any request to `admin/*` should be rerouted to the CMS plugin.