# Disable cache for Cake 2.0 plugin?

Tags: cakephp, caching, plugins, cakephp-2.0

I would like to disable the cache for a self-developed Cake plugin. Is this possible and if so, how would I do this? The reason why is related to an earlier [question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647229/caching-plugin-and-normal-controllers-with-duplicate-names/), where duplicate controller names break parts of my application which were working fine in 1.3.

I know one can disable the Cache by setting the following option in Core.php:

```
Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);
```

I thought it would be possible to do the same in PluginAppController.php in the `beforeFilter` or `beforeRender` method, but that doesn't seem to be working.

Does anybody know if it's possible to do from the PluginAppController or if there are any other options? Disabling the entire cache is very undesirable as it slows down the rest of the application considerably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like poor application architecture.  You shouldn't have to disable the cache -- which sounds like it is a bandaid for a larger problem.  Why don't you simply rename one of the controllers or add some sort of pseudo namespace naming convention in your app to prevent the issue?

Comment: Poor architecture perhaps, but I was under the impression plugins that were completely separate entities. So you're right, I shouldn't have to disable the cache. It is indeed a bandaid until I properly rename all of the offending controllers.

Comment: They are separate entities, but cake loads all used classes when you run the application.  Since CakePHP doesn't use namespaces, because php didn't support it before 5.3, the limitation occures because of php itself, rather than cake.  So even though a plugin and the main app are conceptually separate, they are still susceptible to the limitations of the programming language.

Comment: Yes, I know that now from the various issue reports in the Cake bug tracker. Though my original question still stands, is it possible to disable the Cake cache for certain controllers?

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer is no.