# cakephp plugin model/controller cache issue with main model/controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a plugin with user model, profile model and an user controller, in this user model is associated with profile model. In my main model folder (under app), I have user model and user controller(here I have not associated with profile). Sometimes I'm getting errors saying that user model is not associated with profile model. Also sometimes I'm getting the error - "missing action logout in users controller". I have given the logout action in the app/controller/userscontroller but that method is not available in myplugin/usercontroller. Im using cakephp2.0.. How can I solve this issue ? How cakephp is setting the cache for models and controllers ? I don't want to completely disable the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had trouble with this as well. Basically it comes down to the fact that Cake doesn't support controllers with the same class name. So a controller named `UsersController` on plugin and app level will cause trouble with caching and some components (the `Auth` component, for example).

Support for identical classnames in various levels of a Cake application will come in Cake 3.0 which will require PHP 5.3, which in turn supports namespaces, a feature needed for correctly handling duplicate class names.

With no word on when Cake 3.0 will be released as the 2.0 branch is just out of beta, I refactored my plugin by prepending the plugin name to my controllers, views and models.

So `UserModel` became `PluginUserModel` and `UsersController` became `PluginUsersController`. It's a bit of a hassle, because you have to update all the views and variables which use the model's name.

[My original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647229/caching-plugin-and-normal-controllers-with-duplicate-names) contains some links to the Cake bug tracker where similar questions were raised, should you be interested in some background,

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Exactly, this is what Im looking for.. Have you applied the file given in the bug (http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2378 ) ?

Comment: I did, but it doesn't seem to resolve the problem. `cake_core_file_map` is still populated with conflicting references to the controllers and it probably still causes other problems. This report, http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/1884,  details the fix and has some developer response. Refactoring the controllers, views and models is probably the safest bet.

Comment: I tried to rename the files and changed class names (by prefixed with plugin name), but getting errors. Can you provide an example ? and how to give the association in that case?

Comment: What errors are you getting? If you change the classnames of the controllers and models, the filenames (including the view files and directories) should change as well to reflect the renaming. Associations should be referred to `PluginUser` instead of just `User`.

Comment: Missing controller. Error: Admin.UsersController could not be found. Create the class UsersController below in file: app/Plugin/Admin/Controller/UsersController.php . My plugin name is Admin and I renamed my UsersController.php to AdminUsersController.php, And Im accessing it as domain/admin/users

Comment: Ah yes, because of the renaming, paths will have changed. So http://www.yourdomain.com/admin/users will become http://www.yourdomain.com/admin/plugin_users. If you want to support the old URL scheme, you have to do some rerouting in `routes.php`: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

Comment: When access it by giving admin/admin_users , Im getting Missing Database Table
Error: Database table admin_users for model AdminUser was not found.

Comment: Cake expects a different database table based on the renamed model. Use the `$useTable` model attribute to set the correct table. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html

Comment: Im facing the following issues with the above changes.

Comment: 1) I need to access the url with domain.com/admin/admin_users/index or admin/content/index, instead I want to access by admin/users/index or admin/content/index. How to set this in routes in general way. 2) In view, it is showing undefined index User (I have baked the views before). Everything is coming as AdminUser. After setting public $alias = 'User' this issue has been solved. Is this correct ? 3) Need to change "$this->User->some var/fn " to $this->AdminUser->some var/function is all places in the controller. Any way to solve this ?

Comment: I think it's better to ask these 3 as a separate question. Answering goes beyond the scope of a normal comment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031623/cakephp-plugin-model-name-prefix/9032242#9032242